# Converting array to string fails in react render -Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to convert an array prop into a string:

```
   export default class MyComp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let type = this.props.type; // [".abc",".ded",".ted"];
        newType = type.join();
//o/p: newType= ".abc,.ded,.ted"

console.log(newType) // ".abc,.ded,.ted"
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="file" accept={newType}/> //here throws error 
    </div>
    )

    }

}

export default class SubComp extends React.Component{
   render() {
     <Mycomp type={[".abc",".ded",".ted"]}/>

 }
}
```

when I try to access `newType` as a values to the `accept` html, it throws:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined`.
One thing I checked here if I try to pass the hard code values to `newType` it gets working fine. Only when Im trying to convert the array to string using `.join()` or `.toString()`, it fails.

```
render() {
            let type = this.props.type; // [".abc",".ded",".ted"];
            newType = ".abc,.ded,.ted";
        return (
          <div>
          <input type="file" accept={newType}/> //Works Fine!!!! 
        </div>
        )

        }
```

Any idea what may be causing the issue?

Comment: did you console.log out type? after getting it from the props?

Comment: yes, the ```type``` is an array and ```newType``` get converted to string

Comment: please share the code from where you are passing props. it seems like `type` is undefined.

Comment: Use a linter...

Comment: Did you notice you have a typo?  "newType" vs "newtype"

Comment: I edited the props per the suggestions, looks like these were the typos I had while posting the question, but in actual code I do have the props defined wrapped in curly braces. These fixes however didnt help me ..:( not sure where excatly is the issue?

Comment: one thing is still missing `newType = type.join()` should be `const newType = type.join()`.

Comment: tried that as well, but invain..:(

Comment: @user1234 So did you actually solve the problem? I noticed you accepted my answer, but in the comments here you seem to be saying those issues I pointed out were just typos in your question and it still didn't work with those corrected.

Comment: yes so there were 2 comp calling the ```MyComp``` component and one of them didnt have the curly braces for the values passed it, that was the comp giving out error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two problems with your code in the example:

1. You have to use curly brackets around prop values that aren't strings, so it should look like this: `<Mycomp type={[".abc",".ded",".ted"]} />`
2. You assign the joined array to `newType`, but then use `newtype` in your `input` tag (note the capitalization difference)

The corrected code would look like this:

```
export default class MyComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let type = this.props.type;
    let newType = type.join();
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" accept={newType}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default class SubComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <Mycomp type={[".abc",".ded",".ted"]} />
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your type prop using curly brackets `{}`, like so:

```
 <Mycomp type={[".abc",".ded",".ted"]}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass data to props like this

```
export default class MyComp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let type = this.props.type; // [".abc",".ded",".ted"];
        let newType = type.join()//converts to string: ".abc,.ded,.ted"
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="file" accept={newType}/> //here throws error 
    </div>
    )

    }

}

export default class SubComp extends React.Component{
   render() {
     <Mycomp type={[".abc",".ded",".ted"]}/>

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the array to prop like this

```
<Mycomp type={[".abc",".ded",".ted"]} />
```